# What does network time means for MySQL queries

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query which has the following performance profile:

```
/* 0 rows affected, 90.908 rows found. 
Duration for 1 query: 0,000 sec. (+ 0,125 sec. network) */
```

Which looks fine, the network time is low. The database is running on localhost.

However I have another query which has the following performance profile:

```
/* 0 rows affected, 28 rows found. 
Duration for 1 query: 0,000 sec. (+ 1,015 sec. network) */
```

What is the network in general? Is it just the time it takes to transport data between server and client?

Comment: how could you get the "(+ 1,015 sec. network)" info ?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez It looks like that he is using HeidiSql. I also want to know how HeidiSql get the network cost, is using JDBC possible to get the network cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be the time needed to transfer response from server to client.